# Scalar subquery producing more than 1 record with partition - SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, subquery, window-functions, partition-by

I have data with two rows as follows:

```
group_id    item_no
weoifne     1
weoifne     2
```

I want to retrieve the max `item_no` for each `group_id`. I'm using this query:

```
SELECT MAX(item_no)
  OVER (PARTITION BY group_id)
FROM my_table;
```

I need only one record because I'm embedding this query in a `CASE WHEN` statement to apply logic based on whether or not `item_no` is the highest value per group.

Desired Output:

```
2
```

Actual Output:

```
2
2
```

How do I modify my query to only output one record with the maximum `item_no` per `group_id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an aggregate function along with **GROUP BY** instead of an window function.

> A window function, also known as an analytic function, computes values over a group of rows and returns a single result for each row. This is different from an aggregate function, which returns a single result for a group of rows.

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/window-function-calls

```sql
SELECT group_id, MAX(item_no)
  FROM my_table
 GROUP BY group_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to use the window function, you can use DISTINCT in your script to get rid of the duplicates as shown below. DISTINCT works across all the columns

```
SELECT  DISTINCT    group_id
                    , MAX(item_no) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id)
FROM                my_table
```